# Plot line chart data with x-axis and y-axis value in a separate array using d3

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, data-visualization, linechart

I get the data from the backend as an array of objects. I am doing some client side modification of data make it as,

```
var lineXData = xValue; // x value is an array of numbers
var lineYData = yValue; // y value is an array of numbers
```

I was going through an example, where they are constructing the line as,

```
 var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
   .x(function (d) {
      return xRange(d.x);
   })
   .y(function (d) {
      return yRange(d.y);
   })
   .interpolate('basis');

 vis.append("svg:path")
   .attr("d", lineFunc(lineData))
   .attr("stroke", "blue")
   .attr("stroke-width", 2)
   .attr("fill", "none");
```

Here is the link to codepen of their example http://codepen.io/jay3dec/pen/wKLBx/

In my case, the x-axis and y-axis data are in different arrays. How do I pass x-axis array to xrange and yaxis array to y range inside lineFunc? Is this possible? Or is it wrong to do it using this approach in d3?

Comment: the best is to merge the two array into one something like the linedata in your codepen

Comment: It would have been much easier if there was a way to pass individually. Now, I will have to construct the object and push it, so as to make it look like in the codepen. Will try that and let you all know how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: Things are working fine. Looks like merging them is the appropriate way to do it. Thanks Cyril.